# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body ESlint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, arrow-functions

Why is this piece of code giving me lint warnings? What's the workaround? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(
      rootReducer,
      middleware
    );
};
```

That's my eslint configuration

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "object-curly-spacing": 0,
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
      "error",
      {
        "max": 1
      }
    ],
    "arrow-body-style": 1,
    "newline-per-chained-call": 1
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "mocha": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to debug not knowing your particular lint config.

My only guess is that your linter is configured in a way that complains if you use a block on an arrow body which contains only a single expression

Try

```
const configureStore = () =>
  createStore(rootReducer, middleware);
```

If that doesn't work, please provide a comment

--

ps, if you paste your exact code in [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/babel), there are no lint warnings

Comment: It removed the lint warning but the app's stopped working. It doesn't get the `createStore`

Comment: "It doesn't get the `createStore`" - what exactly does that mean? is `createStore` in your module's scope ?

Comment: `Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Login)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Login)".`

Comment: And yes it is. I am importing `createStore` from redux.

Comment: OK, that's a completely separate issue. That error has nothing to do with `configureStore`, `createStore`, `rootReducer` or `middleware`.

Comment: Yeah but I get this only when I tried replacing your answer. It has resolved the lint warning but it has produced a new error which I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Well there is some other problem then. The function provided in this answer is 100% equivalent to the function in your question. I'm afraid without seeing more of your code I won't be able to help you further. If you plan on seeking additional help, please ask a new question instead of modifying this one. Good luck !

Comment: The *last* thing I can think of is that I didn't include a semicolon in mine. The only time I can see this having an impact is if the next expression after your const declaration began with `(`

Comment: Okay what exactly do you need to see related to the code? I can make a new question and would paste the link here.

Comment: You'll need to share where you assign `store`, (`const store = ...`) and how `store` is passed into your `App`, `Provider`, `Root`, etc component

Comment: I figured it out myself. This has been resolved. Thank you for your help. I have marked your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Is there any better approach for this rule? Just asking.

Comment: Approach for what rule ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const configureStore = () => {
  return createStore(
      rootReducer,
      middleware
    );
};
```

change the brace after arrow to bracket

```
const configureStore = () => (
       createStore(
          rootReducer,
          middleware
        );
    );
```

It works to me.
This is the topic about arrow-body--stylehttps://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style.html

> Require braces in arrow function body (arrow-body-style)
>   Options
>   The rule takes one or two options. The first is a string, which can be:
>
> - "always" enforces braces around the function body
> - "as-needed" enforces no braces where they can be omitted (default)
> - "never" enforces no braces around the function body (constrains arrow functions to the role of returning an expression)
>     when you config as-needed

```
//this is a bad style    
let foo = () => {
        return {
           bar: {
                foo: 1,
                bar: 2,
            }
        };
    };
// This is good
let foo = () => ({
    bar: {
        foo: 1,
        bar: 2,
    }
});
```

You can find more detail from  https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style.html#as-needed